# Can I serialize a Delphi TPersistent as a field of TComponent using the default WriteComponent action?

Tags: delphi, serialization, tpersistent, tcomponent

I'm getting very confused about how to write out properties from a TComponent that has a TPersistent field. For example I have:

```
  TChildObj = class( TPersistent )
  PRIVATE
    FVisible: boolean;
    FColor: TColor;
  PUBLIC
  PUBLISHED
    property Visible : boolean
               read FVisible
               write FVisible;
    property Color : TColor
               read FColor
               write FColor;
  end;


  TTest = class( TComponent )
    constructor Create( AOwner : TComponent ); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    FChildObj : TChildObj;
    FOne: integer;
  published
    property One : integer
               read FOne
               write FOne;
    property ChildObj : TChildObj
               read FChildObj;
  end;
```

When I use the following writer code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  SS : TStringStream;
  Test : TTest;
begin
  Test := TTest.Create( Self );
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    MS.WriteComponent( Test );
    MS.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText( MS, SS );
    SS.SaveToFile( 'c:\scratch\test.txt' );
  finally
    MS.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;

end;
```

I get only the following:

```
object TTest
  One = 0
end
```

i.e the TPersistent TChildObj is missing.

[This article](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/component-serialization.html) on component seriealization states "A Component will stream by default any property of type TPersistent that is not a TComponent. Our TPersistent property is streamed just like a component, and it may have other TPersistent properties that will get streamed." however when I step into System.Classes, at around line 12950 (XE3) there is the test:

```
  if (PropInfo^.GetProc <> nil) and
     ((PropInfo^.SetProc <> nil) or
     ((PropInfo^.PropType^.Kind = tkClass) and
      (TObject(GetOrdProp(Instance, PropInfo)) is TComponent) and
      (csSubComponent in TComponent(GetOrdProp(Instance, PropInfo)).ComponentStyle))) then
```

which seems to indicate that only components and sub-components are serialised. If I make TChildObj descend from TComponent (and give it a name) I get its name appearing in the written file (but still no properties).

What I really dont understand is that TControl (a component) has the Font property (TPersistent) and this gets streamed out fine when you write a TLabel for example.

Or is this something to do with default properties?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *"If I make TChildObj descend from TComponent ..."* Call `SetSubComponent(True)` on FChildObj.

Comment: *"TPersistent TChildObj is missing"* - Your FChildObj is read only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look more closely at the list of requirements when the RTL is deciding if it needs to stream a `TPersistent` property:

```
if (PropInfo^.GetProc <> nil) and
 ((PropInfo^.SetProc <> nil) or
 ((PropInfo^.PropType^.Kind = tkClass) and
  (TObject(GetOrdProp(Instance, PropInfo)) is TComponent) and
  (csSubComponent in TComponent(GetOrdProp(Instance, PropInfo)).ComponentStyle))) then
```

Your `ChildObj` property is a read-only property, so it does not satisfy the `PropInfo^.SetProc <> nil` requirement, and it is not a `TComponent`-derived sub-component, so it does not satisfy the is `is TComponent` and `csSubComponent` requirements.  That is why your property is missing from the DFM.

The simpliest solution is to make your `ChildObj` property be read/write instead of read-only (don't use `TComponent` unless you have to, which you don't in this situation).

You are also missing a destructor in `TTest` to free the `TChildObj` object.  And for good measure, you should give `TChildObj` an `OnChange` event that `TTest` can assign a handler to, so it can react to changes to the `TChildObj` sub-properties.

Try this:

```
type
  TChildObj = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FVisible : Boolean;
    FColor : TColor;
    FOnChange : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Changed;
    procedure SetVisible(Value : Boolean);
    procedure SetColor(Value : TColor);
  public
    procedure Assign(Source : TPersistent); override;
    property OnChange : TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  published
    property Visible : Boolean read FVisible write SetVisible;
    property Color : TColor read FColor write SetColor;
  end;

  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    FChildObj : TChildObj;
    FOne : integer;
    procedure ChildObjChanged(Sender : TObject);
    procedure SetChildObj(Value : TChildObj);
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property One : integer read FOne write FOne;
    property ChildObj : TChildObj read FChildObj write SetChildObj;
  end;
```

.

```
procedure TChildObj.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TChildObj then
  begin
    FVisible := TChildObj(Source).Visible;
    FColor := TChildObj(Source).Color;
    Changed;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TChildObj.Changed;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TChildObj.SetVisible(Value : Boolean);
begin
  if FVisible <> Value then
  begin
    FVisible := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TChildObj.SetColor(Value : TColor);
begin
  if FColor <> Value then
  begin
    FColor := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

constructor TTest.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FChildObj := TChildObj.Create;
  FChildObj.OnChange := ChildObjChanged;
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  FChildObj.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTest.ChildObjChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if csLoading in ComponentState then Exit;
  // use ChildObj values as needed...
end;

procedure TTest.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  ChildObjChanged(nil);
end;

procedure TTest.SetChildObj(Value : TChildObj);
begin
  if FChildObj <> Value then
    FChildObj.Assign(Value);
end;
```

If you go the `TComponent` approach, then try this instead:

```
type
  TChildObj = class(TComponent)
  private
    FVisible : Boolean;
    FColor : TColor;
    FOnChange : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Changed;
    procedure SetVisible(Value : Boolean);
    procedure SetColor(Value : TColor);
  public
    procedure Assign(Source : TPersistent); override;
    property OnChange : TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  published
    property Visible : Boolean read FVisible write SetVisible;
    property Color : TColor read FColor write SetColor;
  end;

  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    FChildObj : TChildObj;
    FOne : integer;
    procedure ChildObjChanged(Sender : TObject);
    procedure SetChildObj(Value : TChildObj);
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  published
    property One : integer read FOne write FOne;
    property ChildObj : TChildObj read FChildObj write SetChildObj;
  end;
```

.

```
procedure TChildObj.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TChildObj then
  begin
    FVisible := TChildObj(Source).Visible;
    FColor := TChildObj(Source).Color;
    Changed;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TChildObj.Changed;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TChildObj.SetVisible(Value : Boolean);
begin
  if FVisible <> Value then
  begin
    FVisible := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TChildObj.SetColor(Value : TColor);
begin
  if FColor <> Value then
  begin
    FColor := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

constructor TTest.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FChildObj := TChildObj.Create(Self);
  FChildObj.SetSubComponent(True);
  FChildObj.OnChange := ChildObjChanged;
end;

procedure TTest.ChildObjChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
  if csLoading in ComponentState then Exit;
  // use ChildObj values as needed...
end;

procedure TTest.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  ChildObjChanged(nil);
end;

procedure TTest.SetChildObj(Value : TChildObj);
begin
  if FChildObj <> Value then
    FChildObj.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a concise analysis. As you suggested, it turns out that I needed read-write properties for my TPersistents. I have also updated my example code to add my 'Destroy' destructor to accurately reflect my original code.